# AddAuthentication and SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm troubleshooting a problem with authentication in an ASP.NET Core Web-API project and I want to see if there is something I am missing in terms of my use of `SimpleInjector` as my chosen DI framework.

**OP Update**
This is not an issue with `SimpleInjector` as I initially suspected. The crosswiring stuff is working and the problem was with the `OpenIdConnect` stuff.

Microsoft moved authentication configuration from middleware to services. So, you now add code like the following to configure Auth stuff:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://identityserver.staging.blabla.org";

        options.ClientId = "someweirdstring";
        options.ClientSecret = "someweirderstring";
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Token;

        options.CallbackPath = "/";

        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.Scope.Add("api");

        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnTicketReceived = e =>
            {
                var ctx = e;
                //ClaimsPrincipal p = TransformClaims(e.Ticket.Principal);
                //e.Ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                //    p,
                //    e.Ticket.Properties,
                //    e.Ticket.AuthenticationScheme);

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    })
    .AddCookie();
```

Then you add it to the middleware pipeline.

The issue I am troubleshooting is that this seems to be ineffective when I fire an http request with a valid token in the headers. The `OnTicketReceived` event is not firing at all.

It dawned on me that I was probably supposed to add some code to wire this up with `SimpleInjector`. But how?

I've used the `CrossWire` feature to automagically wire up some of the AspNetCore features:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(container));
services.AddSingleton<IViewComponentActivator>(new SimpleInjectorViewComponentActivator(container));

services.EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring(container);
services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container);
```

And I have tried adding the following line as a bit of a long shot to wire up the `AuthenticationService`:

```
container.Register<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
```

But otherwise, I'm at a bit of a loss. By abstracting away stuff in the `AddAuthentication` method, I've no idea how the `AuthenticationService` is meant to be wired up with a 3rd party container (if at all).

And as stated at the top, I'm not even 100% sure the problem is the way that I have used `SimpleInjector`.

But if I add an `Authorize` attribute to a method, an exception is chucked which says:

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there > was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+d__11.MoveNext()

Any guidance would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line of code

`.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>`

with ...

`.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>`

... should fix the exception.

---

And if I get it right, you will probably run into another exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from ...

If that was the case, adding cookies will fix it.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) // Add this line
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
```

Comment: Thanks. That did fix that exception. I have a new exception Unable to obtain configuration from `'https://identityserver.staging.blablabla.bla/.well-known/openid-configuration` . I'm not sure if I'm there yet, because even if I solve this exception, I'll need to see if the event I mentioned gets fired. However, I'm marking your answer as correct as I believe it solved the exception I listed. Just noting that I may still have a wiring problem. Will report back here in time. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: I have updated the answer. You obviously typed faster than I did :D

Comment: Thanks again Cu. I'm still battling the same exception, but I don't think that is related to the Startup configuration anymore. Will keep investigating.